# Simplifying  equation using algebraic manipulations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I am trying to calculate the input impedance of a multiple feedback low pass filter. What I need is the simplest symbolic expression so that later I fill in the values and get the impedence itself:

[image]

I assume that I am on the right track in calculation, the thing is I can not go any further and simplify the equation more. Can someone please help with putting calculated $V_2$ (down in the writings) into equation $(2)$ and then put $V_{in}$ into equation $(1)$ and simplify it so that $i_1$ will be removed?

So the question is how to substitute and simplify to get a clear $Z_{in}$ with no current in the final equation.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I know how painful those equations will be ; you will probably have a more successful answer if you post this on physics stack exchange or something.

Comment: I agree with Patrick: I think http://physics.stackexchange.com/ would yield you better answers.

Comment: Actually from the description it sounds like the question is just asking about some algebraic manipulations, namely how to substitute $V_2$ into $V_\text{in} = V_2 + i_1R_1$ and simplify it. If that's the case it will be off topic on Physics.

Comment: [Cross-posted to EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26493); voted to close here.

Comment: I also voted to close. Please don't crosspost without at least notifying both communities; think of all the effort wasted if people think about this problem without knowing about the results obtained at the other site.

Comment: I definetly gave up for getting my answer on the electronics site, that is why I am asking here...otherwise I would not like to waste time of anyone really!

Comment: You waited less than a day, as in "Rome wasn't built in a."

Comment: First a non mathematical comment. The first equation for $V_{out}$ assumes as indicated in the handmade diagram that the amplifier's inverting input voltage is $0$ V. Are you given this information?  Concerning your algebraic computation, I found no errors.

Comment: I am not sure if input voltage of negative input should be 0...I just took it by guess...hope I was right otherwise I am in deep ... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried answering in electronics.stackexchange.com, but it seems that LaTeX isn't supported there.  The derivation seems to be correct.

$v_2=\frac{i_1}{sC_2+\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{sC_5R_3+1}{sC_5R_3R_4}}=i_1\frac{sC_5R_3R_4}{s^2C_2C_5R_3R_4+sC_5R_4+sC_5R_3+1}$

$Z_{in}=\frac{V_{in}}{i_1}=\frac{v_2+i_1R_1}{i_1}=\frac{sC_5R_3R_4}{s^2C_2C_5R_3R_4+sC_5R_4+sC_5R_3+1}+R_1$

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check the values and report back if this is correct!

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks again your answer was correct (Checked it with LTSpice simulation)